# VBA skips a For loop - why?

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop

I have this VBA code in MS Word Visual Basic Editor;

It is meant to reset the page numbers so that they work consecutively. However, it seems to skip the entire contents of the loop without executing this.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
' Test 3
'
Dim GetNumberOfPages

    For IncVar = 1 To GetNumberOfPages
        WordBasic.ViewFooterOnly
        ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries(" Blank").Insert _
            Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
        WordBasic.ViewFooterOnly
        ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("Plain Number 3"). _
            Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
        Selection.WholeStory
        With Selection.Sections(IncVar).Headers(IncVar).PageNumbers
            .NumberStyle = wdPageNumberStyleArabic
            .HeadingLevelForChapter = 0
            .IncludeChapterNumber = False
            .ChapterPageSeparator = wdSeparatorHyphen
            .RestartNumberingAtSection = False
            .StartingNumber = 0
        End With
        Selection.WholeStory
        Selection.EscapeKey
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = Not ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View. _
            ShowAll
        Selection.EscapeKey
        Selection.EscapeKey
    Next IncVar
End Sub
```

Why is this?
How can I fix it?

Thanks,

Barry Smith

Comment: `GetNumberOfPages` is not assigned

Comment: Kindly define GetNumberOfPages with proper data type and assign a value before looping

Answer (score 5):

If you use `f8` to `Step Into...` your sequence and check the value of `GetNumberOfPages` you will see that the `GetNumberOfPages = Empty` and the entire loop is skipped

Comment: Thank! That's really helpful... but how can I make a script that returns the number of pages in the document?

Comment: You can simply use `GetNumberOfPages = 10` if you know you have ten pages. Otherwise you need to call some method that returns the number of pages such as outlined on this page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185509

Comment: Btw. value of variable GetNumberOfPages is not False but Empty (it is of type Variant).

Answer (score 3):

`GetNumberOfPages` is a variable, which by default is blank.

You first need to assign some value to it, e.g.

```
Dim numberOfPages as Integer
Dim currentPage as Integer
numberOfPages = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)
For currentPage = 1 To numberOfPages
    ...
Next currentPage
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you are thinking in that way

```
Dim GetNumberOfPages as integer = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages) //check the syntax . i'm not sure.
```

But forget to initilize the `GetNumberOfPages`